# Copy specific file from source directory to target directory and sub-directories using batch script

Tags: batch-file, robocopy

I want to copy a specific file to a target directory structure meaning to all folders and sub-folder and sub-sub-folder. Basically to a directory tree.

I tried using robocopy, but it has only option to defile level on source and not on target

This is what I have tried so far with robocopy and simple batch

```
:: copies to only one target directory
robocopy "%SOURCE_FILE_DIR_PATH%" "%TARGET_ROOT_FOLDER_PATH%" %FILE_NAME%
:: copies to only 1 sub-level
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b "%TARGET_ROOT_FOLDER_PATH%"') do (
    for /f "delims=" %%b in ('dir /b "%TARGET_ROOT_FOLDER_PATH%\%%a"') 
    do (
        copy /y "%FILE_NAME%" "%TARGET_ROOT_FOLDER_PATH%\%%a\%%b"    
    )
)
```

Comment: Please explain with an example what the issue is in using `RoboCopy` with its `/Lev` option.

Comment: @Compo, I think the OP is trying to scatter a single file across a directory tree. I don't think robocopy can do that.

Comment: @Compo As jwdonahue said, the problem with Robocopy with /Lev is that the level is for source and not for target. I need to define it for target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine the `/D` and `/R` options to iterate a directory tree.  So I think this would work for you.

```
set "TARGET_ROOT_FOLDER_PATH=C:\folder\subfolder"
set "FILE_NAME=foo.txt"
FOR /D /R "%TARGET_ROOT_FOLDER_PATH%" %%G IN (*) DO COPY /y "%FILE_NAME%" "%%G"
```

You could modify your code slightly to use the `/AD` and `/S` options of the `DIR` command.

```
for /f "delims=" %%G in ('dir /ad /b /s "%TARGET_ROOT_FOLDER_PATH%"') do copy  "%FILE_NAME%" "%%G"
```